# Number theory: Problem involving rational numbers

Tags: random, number-theory

Use `RandomRat` to test whether `((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q]` is identical with `(-1)^q`. Use `25000` rational numbers between `1` and `500000`. Use `Delta =10^-10` and `Map` it to a large list of random rational numbers. If you always get `True` you have evidence for the identity.

Then, show that

```
((-1)^Numerator[q])^(1/Denominator[q])==(-1)^q
```

is not an identity.

---

So far this is what I have:

```
RandomRat := ((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^(Numerator[q])
(-1)^q == RandomRat
```

I'm not sure if that's correct so far because I think I'd have to use pure functions and then how would I use the `25000` rational  numbers between `1` and `500000` from here?

Answer (score 3):

Be careful. You cannot prove an identity through a finite number of tests!

However, you can test the identity directly.

```
ClearAll[q]
((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] === (-1)^q
```

> True

---

In fact, the two terms have the same underlying representation:

```
((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] // FullForm
(-1)^q // FullForm
```

> Power[-1, q]
>   Power[-1, q]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow

Comment: You said, "Use RandomRat to test whether ((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] is identical with (-1)^q."  But because `q` comes from an infinite set, you would need to test `((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] == (-1)^q` for infinitely many values of q, which is impossible.  (btw, I didn't prove that the equation is an identity. However, I did show that Mathematica regards the statement as an identity.)

Comment: I think the main question I have regarding this question is testing this using the given of.... 25000 rational numbers between 1 and 500000. Use Delta =10^-10 and Map it to a large list of random rational numbers

Comment: I don't see how Delta has to do with anything the question is asking, but it's being asked and I was wondering if anyone can clarify it

Comment: @Sam I usually think it's the teacher's job to clarify his or her questions.  If it's from a textbook, then perhaps there's some context you're overlooking or it's a poorly worded question.

Answer (score 1):

First, the beginning of the statement "Use `RandomRat`..." strongly indicates to the reader that a function `RandomRat` has already been defined and a solution should implement that particular function. If this problem is copied from a class or book, then the definition should be in the problem, in class, or in the book.  The rest of the problem leads me to guess that `RandomRat` should be returning a random rational number.  I further suspect that `Delta` is an argument to this function.  You can't really generate random rational numbers in an interval with imposing some limitation on the distribution; I suspect in this case limiting the size of the denominators is done by passing `Delta` as the second argument of `Rationalize`.

Here is my interpretation:  First, a list `ratlist` of 25000 random rational numbers.

```
SeedRandom[1];
Delta = 10^-10;
ratlist = Rationalize[#, Delta] & /@ RandomReal[{1, 500000}, 25000];
```

We can `Map` (`/@`) the first test onto this list:

```
Function[{q}, ((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] == (-1)^q] /@ 
  ratlist // DeleteDuplicates
(* {True} *)
```

That the second equation is not an identity is shown by most rational numbers, such as `q -> 2/3`.

Comment: +1 For the helpful comments (and speculation about the author's aims) at  the beginning of your posting.

Answer (score 0):

Here I check the first 25000 rats instead of 25000 random rats.

```
test1[q_] := (-1)^q == ((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^(Numerator[q]);
test2[q_] := (-1)^q == ((-1)^(Numerator[q]))^(1/Denominator[q]);
list = Union@Flatten@Outer[#1/#2 &, Range[#], Range[#]] &@203;
test1 /@ list // Union
test2 /@ list // Union
```

If you have a long list of rats, you can use `RandomChoice` to get a random one.

Alternatively, you could construct a random rat

```
RandomRat:=#1/#2 & @@ RandomInteger[{1, 500000}, 2]
```

Comment: What do I do with the delta=10^-10 part?

Comment: I don't understand what the delta was for, unless he was asking you to choose rational numbers from the list `list=Range[1,500000,10^-10]`