# map rational number

Tags: random, map

I am trying to **map** this function

```
((-1)^(1/Denominator[#]))^Numerator[#]==(-1)^#&
```

to a fairly big list of random rational numbers

I am trying to get this to give me a result of true, so I mapped that above function to

```
RandomRandomRational[{bound1_, bound2_}, delta_, n_]]
```

but I don't get true as my result.

---

I also wanted to try to see if `((-1)^Numerator[q])^(1/Denominator[q])==(-1)^q` is an identity or not, so would I do the same as above, but my result should show up negative?

Comment: Looks familiar: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34427/1783

Comment: @belisarius- I want to learn a math program for a job so my friend said to try mathematica and if I get used to it go learn python, I think it's called.  and bill - I will take a look at that thank you.

Comment: Your friend's counsel (learning Mathematica as a first step for python) doesn't sound efficient to me.

Comment: He said learning this program is easier than learning python which is why I should learn this one first

Comment: There are two alternatives: 1) Your friend doesn't know enough Mathematica or 2) He's playing with you.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your specific question, it's easy enough to map the function to a long list of rational numbers. Here's the function:

```
f[q_] := ((-1)^(1/Denominator[q]))^Numerator[q] == (-1)^q
```

Construct a bunch of "random" rationals from random integers:

```
num = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 1000];
den = RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, 1000];
```

and apply the function to the list:

```
f[#] & /@ (num/den)
```

gives a long list of `True`s.

Comment: I don't think that was what I was looking for but thank you, I think I got it now